# Apache JMeter 3.0 Multipart Request works for POST but not for PUT

Tags: http, jmeter

When I make a multipart request using the POST method to my server, the request works fine.

Below is how I've set up my JMeter:

**POST REQUEST**

[image: POST Request]
[image: POST Response]

However, when I try to make a PUT request to the same URL, the request does not work.

**PUT REQUEST**

[image: PUT Request]
[image: PUT Response]

And the error on the server is

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request

This seems to be an issue on the JMeter, since that when I try to do the same request using **Postman**, the request using POST or PUT works correctly.

However, I want to use JMeter to test my application performance.

**The question is**: How to make PUT multipart request using JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of JMeter 3.0 multipart/form is only available for POST  method, while it appears to be possible for other http methods.

So it's a bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60015

See also:

- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-dev/201609.mbox/%3cCAH9fUpbN5jVSNmJUWTFOQUoRM64LNdKY=j8ZjGWzRt6gDuNzdg@mail.gmail.com%3e

It should be fixed in next releases.

Comment: Hope on release 3.1 this bug is fixed

Comment: I updated answer to be more accurate. If ok you should accept it and upvote.